# stack 3D images to 4D

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to stack 3D images to have 4D array. I have code as:

```
def stack():
   x=None
   dim=(299,299)
   for file in os.listdir(path_to_folder):
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
            img = cv2.imread(path_to_folder+ file)
            image_a = cv2.resize(img,dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

            img2 = cv2.imread(path_to_folder+ file)
            image_p = cv2.resize(img2,dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

            img3 = cv2.imread(path_to_folder+ file)
            image_n = cv2.resize(img3,dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

            if (x is None):
                x=[(image_a),(image_p),(image_n)]
            else:
                x[0]=np.stack((x[0], (image_a)))
                x[1]= np.stack((x[1],(image_p)))
                x[2]=np.stack((x[2],(image_n)))

    return x
```

I am expecting shape as:

```
stack=stack()
stack[0].shape
>>out: (5,299,299,3)

len(stack)
>>out: 3
```

but I am getting `(1495,299,3)`.
Note: for just focusing on real problem I have kept all 3 image files same. i have taken **generate_triplets** function from [here](https://github.com/eroj333/learning-cv-ml/blob/master/SNN/Offline%20Triplet%20Mining.ipynb) , but in my case my images are read from folder.

Comment: Why do you expect the first axis' dimension as 5?

Comment: I am getting the shape `(299,299,3)`

Comment: I have 5 images in my folder.

Comment: i have taken **generate_triplets** function from [here](https://github.com/eroj333/learning-cv-ml/blob/master/SNN/Offline%20Triplet%20Mining.ipynb) , but in my case my images are read from folder.

Comment: You expect the shape of `stack` to be `(5,299,299,3)` right? Not the shape of `stack[0]`?

Comment: stack[0].shape= (5,299,299,3), stack is list of length 3.

Comment: Your code returns the shape of `stack[0].shape` as `(299,299,3)` and `len(stack) = 3`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, and I'll explore some of them. First of all, np.stack requires that all arrays be the same shape. You can't keep calling np.stack repeatedly like this. An easy fix is storing all images in a list, and then calling stack at the very end. Let me whip up some dummy code:

```
import numpy as np

def stack():
    x = [[],[],[]]
    dim = (299,299)
    for i in range(5):
        img_a = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3)
        img_p = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3)
        img_n = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3)

        x[0].append(img_a)
        x[1].append(img_p)
        x[2].append(img_n)

    x = [np.stack(im) for im in x]
    return x

stack = stack()
print(out[0].shape)
```

Out:

```
(5, 299, 299, 3)
3
```

If you do, however, want to stack on every iteration for some reason, you can still do it using vstack. You just have to make each 3d image a 4d image by reshaping.

```
import numpy as np

def stack():
    x = None
    dim = (299,299)
    for i in range(5):
        img_a = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3)
        img_p = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3)
        img_n = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3)

        if (x is None):
            x=[img_a,img_p,img_n]
        else:
            s = (-1,dim[0],dim[1],3)
            x[0]=np.vstack((x[0].reshape(s), img_a.reshape(s)))
            x[1]=np.vstack((x[1].reshape(s), img_p.reshape(s)))
            x[2]=np.vstack((x[2].reshape(s), img_n.reshape(s)))
    return x

stack = stack()
print(stack[0].shape)
print(len(stack))
```

Output:

```
(5, 299, 299, 3)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying @Mercury's function:

```
In [398]: def stack(): 
     ...:     alist = [] 
     ...:     dim = (299,299) 
     ...:     for i in range(5): 
     ...:         img_a = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3) 
     ...:         img_p = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3) 
     ...:         img_n = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3) 
     ...:         alist.append([img_a, img_p, img_n]) 
     ...:     return np.array(alist) 

In [399]: stack().shape                                                                        
Out[399]: (5, 3, 299, 299, 3)
```

`alist` is a nested (5,3) list containing (299,299,3) arrays.  Turned into an array it becomes 5d.

We could just transpose that, `stack().transpose(1,0,2,3,4)`.  But `np.stack` is a concatenate version that lets us specify a `new` axis:

```
In [400]: def stack(): 
     ...:     alist = [] 
     ...:     dim = (299,299) 
     ...:     for i in range(5): 
     ...:         img_a = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3) 
     ...:         img_p = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3) 
     ...:         img_n = np.random.randn(dim[0],dim[1],3) 
     ...:         alist.append([img_a, img_p, img_n]) 
     ...:     return np.stack(alist, axis=1) 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [401]: stack().shape                                                                        
Out[401]: (3, 5, 299, 299, 3)
```